# Convert into matrix table to visualize co-occurrence matrix network (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matrix, text-mining

I have this CSV with this columns:

| ID | Dim | Word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | U | Happy |
| a1 | X | Love |
| a1 | H | Fat |
| a1 | H | Ugly |
| y2 | U | Happy |
| y2 | X | Trust |
| y2 | X | Love |
| pd3 | H | Ugly |
| ed4 | X | Trust |
| ed4 | H | Ugly |

This should give an matrix table with the ocorrence of each "Word" in relation to the presence of others "Words" for each "ID".

For example, it should result in this table:

|  | Happy | Love | Fat | Ugly | Trust |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Love | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Fat | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ugly | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Trust | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

This matrix table should be exported to a new CSV file.

In order to possibilitate the generation of the visualization of co-occurrence matrix network. I want to do it for the column "Dim" e for column "Word", but I believe that is the same process.
And someone know how I can plot this co-occurrence matrix network in Python 3? Or I need another tool to visualize with based on results from matrix table?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you explain the value 2 for example Love-Happy? How do you get 2?

Comment: @Onyambu "Love" occurs  2 times when "Happy" is present, for the same "ID".

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
A = pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Word)
df2 = A.T @ A
np.fill_diagonal(df2.values, 0)

df2

Word   Fat  Happy  Love  Trust  Ugly
Word                                
Fat      0      1     1      0     1
Happy    1      0     2      1     1
Love     1      2     0      1     1
Trust    0      1     1      0     1
Ugly     1      1     1      1     0
```

You can then write the `df2` into a csv file, ie `df2.to_csv('your_output_file.csv')`